# jQuery Slideshow Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a simple slider that will take the div id and change the list items after a few seconds:

Most that I have found are over complex for what I want.

I have a dynamic section of code:

```
<div id="billboard"> 


            <li><img src="http://domain.co.nz/files/large/3/100/75" alt="Banner1.png"/></li> 

            <li><img src="http://domain.co.nz/files/large/4/100/75" alt="Banner2.png"/></li> 

            <li><img src="http://domain.co.nz/files/large/5/100/75" alt="Banner3.png"/></li> 



</div>
```

Comment: does the container have to be a div? since your images are in li elements, a ul container might be more appropriate. And I think sliders typically work with ul lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below url it will do this,

http://www.script-tutorials.com/how-to-create-your-own-jquery-slider-plugin/

watch the demo from - http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/78/index.html

Hope this helps...

Comment: Simple and basic great for development

Answer (score 0):

This one is probably "overly complex", at least in terms of it has a handful of features beyond what you need, but I was able to get it working for a simple use case very easily.

http://slidesjs.com/